# Several colorbars instead one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm creating a signal over noise map in my astrophysic internship project and I get a little problem with my subplot because instead to obtain one colorbar per heatmap, I get 3 colorbars by heatmap like this :

[image: Signal over Noise map]

This is my script (hopfully it will be comprehensible) :

```
# VERIFICATION DE LA CARTE S/N
# convolution_X and convolution_mask_X are arrays

fig10 = plt.subplot(1,3,1)
step1 = convolution_locale - convolution_mask_locale
fig_step1 = plt.imshow(step1, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X (arcmin)")
plt.ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

fig10 = plt.subplot(1,3,2)
step2 = convolution_grande - convolution_mask_grande
fig_step2 = plt.imshow(step2, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X (arcmin)")
plt.ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

fig10 = plt.subplot(1,3,3)
S_N_map = step1 - step2
fig_S_N_map = plt.imshow(S_N_map, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X (arcmin)")
plt.ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

fig10 = plt.savefig(outname10)
```

Do you need more informations about arrays ?

Thank you if you have an idea !

Comment: Maybe you'll change before presenting the figures, but just in case: please help in the fight against the Jet colormap, especially in physics. https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting confused because you are not telling it which colorbar belongs to which subplot.

Using the matplotlib object-oriented approach will help a lot here. If you create your figure and subplot instances (for example using `plt.subplots()`), then you can call the plotting (e.g. `ax1.imshow`) and labelling (e.g. `ax1.set_xlabel`) methods on each of these instances, without needing to use `plt` at all. Then, when you create your colorbars (`fig10.colorbar()`), you can use the `ax` kwarg, to tell it which subplot to create the colorbar next to.

You also give the mappable object (e.g. `fig_step1`) to the call to `fig10.colorbar`, to insure the correct array is being used to create the colorbar scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some fake data
outname10 = 'test.png'
convolution_locale = np.random.rand(250,250)
convolution_mask_locale = np.random.rand(250,250)
convolution_grande = np.random.rand(250,250)
convolution_mask_grande = np.random.rand(250,250)

# use a nice colormap
plt.viridis()

# Create the figure and subplot instances
fig10, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)

step1 = convolution_locale - convolution_mask_locale
fig_step1 = ax1.imshow(step1, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_step1,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

step2 = convolution_grande - convolution_mask_grande
fig_step2 = ax2.imshow(step2, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_step2,ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

S_N_map = step1 - step2
fig_S_N_map = ax3.imshow(S_N_map, interpolation='nearest')
fig10.colorbar(fig_S_N_map,ax=ax3)
ax3.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax3.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

# Create space for labels between subplots
fig10.set_tight_layout(True)

fig10.savefig(outname10)
```

[image]

Comment: plus one for the nice colormap... the code you show is also better than the one I proposed.

Comment: thanks! I can't wait for jet to no longer be the default colormap :)

Comment: Yet, it throws an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'viridis'` - Is that an extra to import or do I need to update matplotlib?

Comment: and a warning: `warnings.warn("tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer")`

Comment: ok, the `AttributeError` is just a version thing: you must be on `matplotlib` version less than 1.5. You can safely remove that line and use a different colormap (viridis was only included from 1.5 onwards)

Comment: changing to `fig10.set_tight_layout(True)` will remove the warning about tight layout. Note that neither of these affect the solution to the OP's question though

Comment: @tom Thank you to your answer ! It's working very well :D
I can apply this kind of process on my others subplots and get something which will be clean :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, fig10 was accumulating redundant color bars; this will produce what you want (I think):

```
# VERIFICATION DE LA CARTE S/N
# convolution_X and convolution_mask_X are arrays
import numpy as np
import random

convolution_locale = np.array([[random.random() for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)])
convolution_grande = np.array([[random.random() for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)])

plt.subplot(1,3,1)
step1 = convolution_locale   #- convolution_mask_locale # uncomment to use your data
fig_step1 = plt.imshow(step1, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X (arcmin)")
plt.ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
plt.show()

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
step2 = convolution_grande  #- convolution_mask_grande # uncomment to use your data
fig_step2 = plt.imshow(step2, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X (arcmin)")
plt.ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
S_N_map = step1 - step2
fig_S_N_map = plt.imshow(S_N_map, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X (arcmin)")
plt.ylabel("Y (arcmin)")

plt.savefig(outname10)
```

Please note that I modified the construction of the arrays that are plotted (indicated in the code)

[image]

Comment: The problem is that step1 and step2 are a difference between two arrays, it's not just one array ^^

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter, it is simple data manipulation. You did not provide the arrays, so I made some up to illustrate the point. You can use this with your own arrays, and manipulate them the way you like before plotting.

Comment: J'ai remis les instructions de soustraction des arrays - il faudra les de-commenter pour utiliser vos donnees.

Comment: Yes, I updated my script and he's running, I am waiting the end of process to see if my problem is resolved ;)